# ios : memory file operator bool crash

Tags: ios, swift, database, nullpointerexception, realm

I am using realmswift in my project, so as per apple guidelines I converted whole project into swift 4.2 and all pod libraries into latest version. Project is converted successfully but I get crash everytime when I run project.

I have uploaded screenshot for better understanding.

[image: Crash image]

Now here is my model for inserting value in database

```
class SyncProductModel: Object, Mappable {
    @objc dynamic var id: String?
    @objc dynamic var productType : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name: String?
    @objc dynamic var category :String?
    @objc dynamic var sku : String?
    @objc dynamic var baseMOQ : Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var isActive : Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var isFavourite : Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var createdAt : String?
    @objc dynamic var updatedAt : String?
    @objc dynamic var uom : String?
    @objc dynamic var productDesc : String?
    @objc dynamic var retailUOM : String?
    @objc dynamic var isInCart : Bool = false
    
    var isSelecetd = false
    var attachments = List<AttachmentModel>()
    var inventory = List<SyncInventoryModel>()
    
    var inventoryModel : SyncInventoryModel?
    
//    var tags = List<tags>()
//    var baseProperties = List<baseProperties>()
    
    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }
    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
    
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        
        id                   <- map["id"]
        productType          <- map["type"]
        name                 <- map["name"]
        category             <- map["category"]
        sku                  <- map["sku"]
        
        var baseQty          : Any?
        baseQty              <- map["baseMOQ"]
        
        baseMOQ              = Utilities.getDoubleValue(value: baseQty)
        isActive             <- map["isActive"]
        createdAt            <- map["createdAt"]
        updatedAt            <- map["updatedAt"]
        uom                  <- map["uom"]
        productDesc          <- map["description"]
        retailUOM            <- map["retailUOM"]

        attachments          <- (map["attachments"], ListTransform<AttachmentModel>())
//        tags                 <- (map["attachments"], ListTransform<tags>())
//        baseProperties       <- (map["baseProperties"], ListTransform<baseProperties>())

    }
```

Here is my code for inserting value into db

```
        for obj in masterProduct
        {
            if self.realm.isInWriteTransaction {
                self.realm.add(obj, update: true)
            }
            else {
                try! self.realm.write {
                    // Here My application get crashed.
                    self.realm.add(obj, update: true)
                }
            }
         }
```

But everytime application get crashed. Please help me I stuck here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "so as per apple guidelines I converted whole project into swift 4.2 and all pod libraries into latest version.". Can you clarify. Do you mean your project is now swift 4.2? Are you building realm from source or using pre-compiled latest version? What is the source file with the crash - is it part of Realm source? What is the stack trace, showing the top-most line of your code. Please add this to question.

Comment: Yes, My project is in swift 4.2. i am building project using latest compiler with new build system. Source file of crash is memory.c++ and i think it is a part of realm source.